# How replace a custom cell with another custom cell in NSTableView

Tags: objective-c, macos, nstableview, custom-cell

I am working on a Mac OS X application. I currently have an `NSTableview` with 3 columns. The second column in the `NSTableView` is populated with a CustomCell say `CustomCell1`.

During run time, I want to replace the content of second column with another CustomCell say
`CustomCell2`. I want this to happen when the tableview cell is selected. I searched a lot but, no help. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Raj

Comment: I want two different cells at 2 different times . Not just changing the existing cell content

Comment: If I understand your requirements correctly, that is what the delegate method `tableView:dataCellForTableColumn:row:` does, as outlined in the accepted answer of the question I linked to.